# Find duplicate lead for partner portal user

Tags: permissions, partner-portal, partner-communities, duplicate-management

I have a requirement to add "Find Duplicates" standard button on Lead object records for partner portal user.
I have the button on layout of other salesforce user but that button is not appearing on partner portal.
For merging lead we require delete permission, but I cannot assign delete permission on lead object for partner user profile nor able to get delete permission in permission set.
I was wondering if dupe catcher will work on partner portal user ?
Please assist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot have delete on Partner profile which uses 'Gold Partner user license' for standard objects. The thought process behind this setup could be to ensure that third parties can see records or to modify it but should not delete them. 'Find Duplicates' or for that matter other de-dupe tools that require 'Lead Delete' permission cannot be used.
Talking about DupeBlocker. It either sends a warning to user when a duplicate is inserted or stops the insertion of record if dupicate is found depending upon predefined configured rule. I dont think delete permission is associated with this so you might be able to install and get this app to work.

Comment: Seems to be a feasible solution, will check & see if it works or not.
Thanks

Comment: did the solution work ?

Comment: that idea was dropped by client i guess. I didn't get any updates from my manager about that.
Thanks for that information